# How to secure Azure Function's backend Storage account?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azureportal

I have created an Azure storage account with private endpoints for blob, file, table and queue. I have set the 'Public network access' to 'Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account' for security.

However, Azure Function creation (via portal) fails unless 'Public network access' is turned on.

Is there a better way to do this other than enabling public network access on storage?

I have checked the below link and there is nothing that suggests that storage needs to be publicly accessible.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli

Error:

```
"properties": {
    "statusCode": "BadRequest",
    "serviceRequestId": null,
    "statusMessage": "{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"Creation of storage file share failed with: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'. Please check if the storage account is accessible.\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":[{\"Message\":\"Creation of storage file share failed with: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'. Please check if the storage account is accessible.\"},{\"Code\":\"BadRequest\"},{\"ErrorEntity\":{\"ExtendedCode\":\"99022\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"Creation of storage file share failed with: '{0}'. Please check if the storage account is accessible.\",\"Parameters\":[\"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.\"],\"Code\":\"BadRequest\",\"Message\":\"Creation of storage file share failed with: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.'. Please check if the storage account is accessible.\"}}],\"Innererror\":null}",
    "eventCategory": "Administrative",
    "entity": "/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/rg-xxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/func-xxxxxxx",
    "message": "Microsoft.Web/sites/write",
    "hierarchy": "xxxxx/MG/MG/xxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find [function app's outbound IP addresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses?tabs=portal#find-outbound-ip-addresses) and [grant access from an internet IP range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-an-internet-ip-range) to those IP addresses. If your function app is VNET integrated, [grant access from a virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ffiles%2Ftoc.json&tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-from-a-virtual-network).

Comment: This issue is upon creation of a function app with an existing storage account. Both the storage and function are o the same vNet. Does that mean that you have to enable public network access, create a function and then secure the storage? What if the storage is already in use and is shared between other existing functions and you want to create a new function using the same storage backend?

Comment: Not faced that specifically but it could be because of the deployment running from outside of VNET. If so, the solution would be to temporarily enable public access during the deployment, as you mentioned. The process isn't going to break anything existing as the access restrictions are relaxed and put back to original values.

Comment: One of the recommendation about storage is to assign unique account for each function app. We don't do that ourselves as it unnecessarily causes proliferation of storage accounts but can be considered